# Ansible Assert on json_query

Tags: json, testing, ansible

I am trying to run an assert in ansible on a result returned from a `json_query`. However, even though the returned value looks like my assert, the assert fails. Here's the assert:

```
- name: Assert environment variables
  assert:
    that:
      - Job | json_query(jmesquery) == "00"
  vars:
    jmesquery: "resources[0].spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[?name=='MY_VARIABLE'].value"
```

A debug run on the same query returns:

```
- name: Test1
  debug: msg="{{ Job | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
  vars:
    jmesquery: "resources[0].spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[?name=='MY_VARIABLE'].value"

TASK [Test1] *******************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "msg": [
            "00"
        ]
    }
```

So why on earth is that assert failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your debug message show it: your result is a list with one element, `"00"`, so your assert should be:

```yaml
- name: Assert environment variables
  assert:
    that:
      - Job | json_query(jmesquery) == ["00"]
  vars:
    jmesquery: "resources[0].spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[?name=='MY_VARIABLE'].value"
```

For the record, here is the debug of a list like yours:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: ["00"]
```

Gives:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "00"
    ]
}
```

And this is the debug of a simple string, like the `assert`, like you wrote it, is expecting:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "00"
```

Gives

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "00"
}
```